# The Tukey HSD test in the multcomp package gives non-contiguous significance letters?

Tags: r

I've only ever seen the compact letter display for Tukey's HSD give contiguous letter groupings but like in the following example this package is giving non-contiguous groupings (ie 'cde' is contiguous whereas 'ac' or 'ce' are not). Is there a way to get it to use the more traditional contiguous letter groupings?

This example is borrowed from another post because it reproduces my results.

```
library(foreign)
yield <- read.dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r12/yield.dta")
tx <- with(yield, interaction(fertilizer, irrigation))
amod <- aov(yield ~ tx, data=yield)
library(agricolae)
HSD.test(amod, "tx", group=TRUE)
library(multcomp)
tuk <- glht(amod, linfct = mcp(tx = "Tukey"))
summary(tuk)          # standard display
tuk.cld <- cld(tuk)   # letter-based display
opar <- par(mai=c(1,1,1.5,1))
plot(tuk.cld)
par(opar)
```

I don't have enough rep to show you the image but here's a link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIiNb.png

The difference between 'cde' and 'c e' is confusing, 'c e' seems to represent an impossible state in which the ends overlap with 'cde' but the middle doesn't. I don't know the interpretation of that (if there is one) and would rather have the standard and expected formatting which has no gaps in the significance lettering.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what these letters mean?

Comment: They are significance letters, anything marked with the same letters are not different from one another.

Comment: Okay. So, if what you get isn't what you want, what exactly should be the output?

Comment: Contiguous lettering as is common for representing Tukey's HSD values. Traditionally lower values would be represented by 'a', the next higher by 'b' and so on, so having one group as 'ac' it's not different from the lower or higher range but it is different from the mid range that it encompasses. Since this is not true of the data it's confusing to have to try to figure out what values the significance letters refer to.

Comment: How many members are in each group?

Comment: Many, it varies between groups but this comparison is between group ranges, so the test is telling whether the range of values covered is different.So this couldn't be explained by gaps if that's what you were thinking.

Comment: I don't understand. Looking at the graph I believe the group with the lowest mean got assigned an "a" and the group with the highest mean an "f" and all others letters in between accordingly. Please provide a reproducible example and the corresponding output you would deem correct and an explanation why you think that would be correct.

Comment: I've edited the question with a full example and better explanation of the problem